# how to fill data from worksheet into 2D array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

if i have data filled in worksheet like shown in image, i want to create a 2D array and fill it with data in such way of the selected cells in the image, i.e to take the 1st value and skip the next two values and so on till the end of the array and by same way in columns

[image: (i),]

i made a solution which delete the intermediate rows and columns but for large array (example of 1000*1000),it takes a lot of time that is why i thought in another way to create array with the above criteria.
this is the code i used for deleting the intermediate rows and columns:

```
Sub Sorting() 
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).rows.count 
For cntr = 1 To LastRow / 3 
rows(cntr + 1 & ":" & cntr + 2).EntireRow.Delete 
Next
Dim LastColumn As Long 
LastColumn = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.count
K = LastColumn 
For cntr = 1 To K / 3 
Columns(cntr + 1).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(cntr + 1).EntireColumn.Delete 
Next
End Sub enter code here
```

Comment: Use a simple 2 x `For` loops, with `Step 3` and read the values to your 2-D array

Comment: 1. Do you want to fill an array with the values from a user-based selection or from a preset stagger/offset collecion of cells? 2. Have you done **nothing** towards a solution on your own beyond creating a pretty image of sample data that everyone else has to retype?

Comment: not from  user based selection. i made a solution which delete the intermediate rows and columns but for large array (examle of 1000*1000),it takes alot of time that is why i thought in another way to create 2Darray with the above criteria

Comment: Your question is not only *too broad*, it's also rather unclear.

Comment: @  Mat's Mug  i reformulated the question

Comment: @  Jeeped  i have reformulated the question with your ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim lRowInterval As Long
    Dim lColInterval As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    lRowInterval = 3
    lColInterval = 3

    aData = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ReDim aResults(1 To Int(UBound(aData, 1) / lRowInterval), 1 To Int(UBound(aData, 2) / lColInterval))

    i = 0
    For lRow = 1 To UBound(aData, 1) Step lRowInterval
        i = i + 1
        j = 0
        For lCol = 1 To UBound(aData, 2) Step lColInterval
            j = j + 1
            aResults(i, j) = aData(lRow, lCol)
        Next lCol
    Next lRow

    'Do what you want with the array aResults here

End Sub
```